# Drupal 8.4 & CiviCRM Issue

Tags: drupal-8, composer

Last evening I tried to follow along with the amazing work @david-snopek posted but I've been running into some issues with the module finding the civicrm "library".

I'm trying to get this working with a [BLT generated project](http://github.com/acquia/blt) and feel like I'm getting pretty close but don't know enough about CiviCRM to know where to look next.

I created a more in depth question here: 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247897/error-installing-civicrm-drupal-8-4-blt-composer-civicrm-must-be-downloa

Resources:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241716/how-to-install-a-module-which-includes-a-different-version-of-symfony/241738
- https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/how-install-civicrm-drupal-8-and-why-choose-it-over-pure-drupal-crm
- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10694

Comment: Hey Justin! I've only used the Snopek method w/ Drupal 8.3.6 thus far - and that all worked - next time I have free time I'll use 8.4 and see if I run into any issues;

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Thanks - I appreciate any help. Definitely struggling trying to get things up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Just looping back - I did get Drupal 8.4.x and CiviCRM 4.7.x up and running - here's my live play by play steps: https://d8webform.semper-it.com/node/4

Comment: thx for sharing